# Apache Velocity importing header from remote URL

Tags: velocity

I have a velocity page, and I need to import a remote header into this page, using a URL. In a normal JSP page, this is quite easy. I can just do

```
<c:import url="http://myURL"/>
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing in Velocity? I am not familiar with this language.

EDIT: I should say, this page is a .vm extension, not in Java itself. In fact, there are no java methods attached to this page. It is not an application that needs to be compiled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Velocity built in, but you can [write a "tool"](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/creatingtools.html) to add this functionality. A tool is simply a Java class, and you can call its methods directly from a Velocity template. For example, if you have written a Java class with a method `fetchURL(String)`, you can call it from Velocity like this:

```
$include.fetchURL("http://example.com/header.html")
```

However, this also requires your class to be known to Velocity under the name of `$include`, which means it must be added to the Velocity context. The VelocityTools framework does this for you after you added your tools to the [toolbox configuration](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/config.html). If you use some other Velocity environment than VelocityTools, it all depends on the environment you use.